# Formatting HashMap to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, hashmap

assuming I have the following HashMap that needed to be converted into JSON:

`HashMap <String, String> test1 = {k1,v1},{k2,v2},{k3,v3},{k4,v4};`

I am aware of using JSONObject to create the JSON output:

`JSONObject json = new JSONObject ( test1 );`

However, the json will be in the following format:
`{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"}`

I would like for the output to be something like this:

```
[{"key":"k1","value":"v1"},
{"key":"k2","value":"v2"},
{"key":"k3","value":"v3"},
{"key":"k4","value":"v4"}]
```

Does anyone have input on how to convert to formatted JSON? Further question: what if the HashMap's key are Set of String?

`HashMap <String, Set<String>> test1 = {k1,{v1,v2,v3}},{k2,{v4,v5,v6}},{k3,{v7,v8,v9}};`

I would like for the output to be something like this:

```
[{"key":"k1","value":["v1","v2","v3"]},
{"key":"k2","value":["v4","v5","v6"]},
{"key":"k3","value":["v7","v8","v9"]}]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: There are some automatic Object -> JSON converter libraries. Jackson is the most used, GSON is also out there :) Both also allow manual construction in which you create `JsonNode`s which you can nest into another, they are like nested `Map<String, JsonObject>`

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes, meant to be array. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with json-simple library you could transform each map entry into a new `JSONObject` first and then add all of them into a `JSONArray`:

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3", "k4", "v4");
JSONArray arr = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> Map.of("key", e.getKey(), "value", e.getValue()))
    .map(JSONObject::new)
    .collect(JSONArray::new, JSONArray::add, JSONArray::addAll);
System.out.println(arr);
```

will print:

```
[{"value":"v4","key":"k4"},{"value":"v3","key":"k3"},{"value":"v2","key":"k2"},{"value":"v1","key":"k1"}]
```

the order of elements in the output `JSONArray` will depend on the map used, you need `LinkedHashMap` if you want to preserve the insertion order when iterating. Otherwise you must order the stream with a comparator.